# elements of list column matching rows in other data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have the following two data.frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Var1=c(3,4,8,9),
               Var2=c(11,32,1,7))

> df1
  Var1 Var2
1    3   11
2    4   32
3    8    1
4    9    7

df2 <- data.frame(ID=c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                ball=I(list(c("3","11", "12"), c("4","1"), c("9","32"))))

> df2
  ID      ball
1  A 3, 11, 12
2  B      4, 1
3  C     9, 32
```

Note that column `ball` in `df2` is a list.

I want to select the `ID` in `df2` with elements in column `ball` that match a row in `df1`.

The ideal output would look like this:

```
> df3
  ID ball1 ball2
1  A     3    11
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this efficiently? The original data consists of millions of rows in both data.frames.

Comment: Can you say what's the `max(sapply(df2$ball, length))`? -- and can there be more than one match?

Comment: df2$ball can have up to 45 elements. These elements can match with multiple rows in df1. Does this help?

Comment: I'm assuming df1 only has the 2 Vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.table` solution would work much more quickly than this base R solution but here is a possibility.

your data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Var1=c(3,4,8,9),
                  Var2=c(11,32,1,7))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                  ball=I(list(c("3","11", "12"), c("4","1"), c("9","32"))))
```

the process:

```
df2$ID <- as.character(df2$ID) # just in case they are levels instead

n <- length(df2)# initialize the size of df3 to be big enough
df3 <- data.frame(ID = character(n),
                  Var1 = numeric(n), Var2 = numeric(n), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F) # to make sure we get the ID as a string
count = 0 # counter
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df2)){
    if(all(df1[i,] %in% df2$ball[[j]])){
      count = count + 1
      df3$ID[count] <- df2$ID[j]
      df3$Var1[count] <- df1$Var1[i]
      df3$Var2[count] <- df1$Var2[i]
    }
  }
}
df3_final <- df3[-which(df3$ID == ""),] # since we overestimated the size of d3
df3_final
```

Comment: This works great. I leave this question open for a bit to see if others have ideas too. Thank you!!

Comment: Curious, how long does this take to run over the large dfs?

Comment: I haven't tried it on an operational data.set yet. But on 60,000+ row data-sets it takes 220 seconds on my machine.